# two objects have same reference are definitely same?

Tags: java, reference, equals

[image]

My question is based on line 26.
Here is my analysis:

```
Class A
{
  intstance variable: Class B;
}
```

If I use

```
A.equals(Class B)
```

Does line 26 return true sometime?

Because in c++, the pointer will point the same address on some circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does line 26 return true sometime?

No, it never returns `true` unless you feed it the same exact object reference.

The reason for it is that Java objects are not "embedded" in one another: there is a reference to `B` inside `A`, but it refers to a completely different object. Hence, no "false aliasing" is possible: the place where the reference to class `B` inside an instance of class `A` is stored is not the same as the place where `B` itself is stored.

Comment: Is there any possibility that two objects share the same memory beginning, while they are not same class(they are not same size)?

Comment: @AlexWei No, object locations in memory cannot overlap. Unlike some other languages, such as C++, which allow embedding objects inside one another, Java objects are included by reference. This more or less corresponds to having a pointer to an object in C++.